# Implicit constructor parameters

Tags: scala

So I tried to work with implicit parameters and variables for the first time and this is working perfectly fine

```
class Test(implicit val a: Int) {

    bar(5)

    def bar(c: Int)(implicit d: Int): Unit = {
        println(d)
    }
}
```

Then I tried it in some more complex code

```
class GameScreen(val game : Game)(implicit val batch: SpriteBatch, implicit val world: World, implicit val manager: AssetManager) extends Screen {

    val camera : OrthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera

    createOpenGLStuff()
    createMap()

    def createMap(implicit w : World) : Unit = 
    {
    }
```

But now I get the error

```
- not enough arguments for method createMap: (implicit w: 
 com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World)Unit. Unspecified value parameter w.
```

I don't know why this is not working, i can write

```
createMap(this.world)
```

And all is well, but since this.world is implicit ( I think? ) I should not need to specify it there. What am I doing/understanding wrong here?

Comment: I hope you don't work with implicit integers in a real project.

Comment: This was just to test how implicit variables behave. Aside from that why are implicit integers bad? I don't have an idea where I would use them, but you never know.

Comment: Usually you only take implicit arguments of very specific types. Integers can be used for many things, but you can only have one implicit value per type hang around. If you have a function taking implicit int as a timeout and another taking an implicit int as a random seed, it may happen that the second function gets an implicit value that was intended to be a timeout.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to drop the parens

```
class GameScreen(val game : Game)(implicit val batch: SpriteBatch, implicit val world:    World, implicit val manager: AssetManager) extends Screen {

  val camera : OrthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera

  createOpenGLStuff()
  createMap //this works

  def createMap(implicit w : World) : Unit = 
  {
  }
```

However, the createMap method has to perform some side-effects, so calling it without parens isn't really a good thing.

I suggest changing to:

```
def createMap()(implicit w : World) : Unit = {
  ...
}
```

This way, you get to maintain the original calling syntax: `createMap()`

Comment: Ah it is so obvious if you see it. Parentheses are always a tricky thing in scala - at least to me.

Comment: I was under the impression that `implicit` marks an entire param list as implicit. What benefit is there in repeating for each parameter here?

Answer (score 3):

Also, you only need the implicit keyword at the beginning of the parameter list:

```
class GameScreen(val game : Game)(implicit val batch: SpriteBatch, val world: World, val manager: AssetManager) extends Screen {...}
```